# array.filter does not return filtered result

Tags: angular6

In my  angular 6 application, I am searching in list so in HTML I have below code.

```
<li *ngFor="let c of listName | search: searchText ; let i = index;" class="advance-list-heading" >
                              <span *ngIf = "i==0" class="test">My List</span>
                              <ul class="advance-list-treeview">
                                <li (click)="SetValue(c.name)">
                              class="row"> -->
                                <span *ngIf="c.name; else noresult">{{c.name}}</span>
                                <!-- </div>  -->
                                </li>
                                </ul>
                          </li>
```

When I select any of the value from search result I want to filter already available result. so I have below function in .ts file

```
SetValue(SelectedList:string) {
      this.inputField.nativeElement.value= SelectedList
      this.divVisible = false;
      return this.listName.filter((x: any) => x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(SelectedList.toLowerCase()))
      // this.ref.detectChanges
      // console.log(this.listName)

    }
```

however the exiting list in page does not get filter can anyone please help me here ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
return this.listName.filter((x: any) => x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(SelectedList.toLowerCase()))
```

try

```
this.listName = this.listName.filter((x: any) => x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(SelectedList.toLowerCase()))
```

Edit:

```
ngOnInit(){
const response = this.getData();
this.completeList = responsee;
this.listName = this.completeList;
}
```

then

```
SetValue(SelectedList:string) {
      this.inputField.nativeElement.value= SelectedList
      this.divVisible = false;
      this.listName = this.completeList.filter((x: any) => x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(SelectedList.toLowerCase()));
    }
```

Comment: This works and  gives me updated result but when user types in searchbox it searches in updated result and not in original result set ( i.e loaded on ngOnInit )

Comment: @hdc Try two arrays, list and filteredList. Use them as per your convenience.

Comment: if you can be more specific please?

Comment: I have listName array bound to HTML, How i can have two arrays here, this helps me to build initial array on ngOnInit() and I want to make sure when user searches it should automatcally fiter out array which was loaded on page load however when I click on text box again and search again it would work

Comment: What I meant was `listName` can be bound to HTML, but while filtering inside the function, you can use an array like `completeList` which contains all the result from your API call. In the success of API call, `this.completeList = reponse from API; this.listName = this.completeList`. Then in the function call `this.listName = this.completeList.filter((x: any) => x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(SelectedList.toLowerCase()))`

Comment: `ngOnInt() {
this.completeList = response;
this.listName = this.completeList;
}`

then 

`SetValue(SelectedList:string) {
      this.inputField.nativeElement.value= SelectedList
      this.divVisible = false;
      this.listName = this.completeList.filter((x: any) => x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(SelectedList.toLowerCase()))
     
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196990/discussion-between-hdc-and-jefferinjoseph).